# HMTL - How to create a button without forwarding to the link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I wanna have a button which I want to press and open HTML web page in background. I don't want to see the site of my link. The link that I have in my code opens a site and this site is just a trigger for an application. So what I want to have is to press the button, execute the link in the background and stay on my site with my buttons.

How can I do that?

Right now I use this code and with this code I will be forwarded to my link. I have always to go back to press the next button.

This is part of my code:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="window.location.href='http://START'" />
</form>
```

Comment: <form>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="window.location.href='http://START'" />
</form>

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Do you want the window with the new page to stay open in the background or never be shown?  - you can target your form to _blank and get a new tab or you can Ajax to run whatever the page is doing

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as follows:

- After clicking a button, you want to open a url, but you don't want the browser to refresh. The url should be opened in the background.

Since javascript is an option, you should look into doing 'Ajax' calls.